# Double free or corruption - error when deleting first node of list

Tags: c, list, struct, nodes

I have the following code to delete elements from a list. When one of the elements of the struct is lower than the value I use it, I must delete the node.

The code is as follows:

```
void DeleteNode(frota** head, int MAX, int nSquareW){
    int i, eliminate = 0;
    frota* curr = *head;
    frota* curr1 = curr;
    if(*head != NULL)
    {
        while(curr1 != NULL)
        {
            if(curr1->bateria < MAX)
            {
                if( *head == curr1){
                    if(curr1->next != NULL){
                        (curr1->next)->prev = NULL;
                    }
                    *head = curr1->next;
                }else if(curr1 -> next == NULL){
                    (curr1->prev)->next = NULL;
                }else{
                    (curr1->next)->prev = curr1->prev;
                    (curr1->prev)->next = curr1->next;
                } 
                eliminate = 1;
             }
             curr1 = curr1->next;
             if(eliminate == 1){
                 eliminate = 0;
                 printf("entrei1");
                 for(i=0;i<nSquareW;i++){
                     free(curr->percorridos[i]);
                 }
                 free(curr->percorridos);
                 free(curr);
             }
             curr = curr1;   
         }
    }
}
```

The code is working well when I try to delete the last and middle nodes (value head is equal to first node, unless there is none, then value is NULL), but when I try to delete the first node, I get the following error:

`*** Error in './iClean': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x09bd4a20 ***`

Someone has already told me that the problem is when deleting the node (the free() ) and that I can't do anything about that.

Any help would be appreciate.

**EDIT**

nSquareWidth is the width of the map.

This is the code which generates percorridos:

```
void faz_mapa(matriz *** mapa, int nSquareW, int nSquareH){

    *mapa = malloc(nSquareW * sizeof(matriz*));
    for (int i = 0; i < nSquareW; i++)
    {
        (*mapa)[i]= malloc( nSquareH * sizeof(matriz));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nSquareW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nSquareH; j++)
        {

        //inicializa divisao suja
        (*mapa)[i][j].limpo = 0;
        (*mapa)[i][j].ocupado = NULL;
        }   
    }

}
```

And struct:

```
typedef struct robot {
   int bateria;
   char nome[STRING_SIZE];
   int pos_x;
   int pos_y;
   int target_x;
   int target_y;
   int limpos;
   matriz ** percorridos;
   struct robot * next;
   struct robot * prev;
}frota;
```

Comment: You can do something about it.  Leaving a double free or corruption of heap in your code won't run so it has to be fixed.  That someone who told you that was wrong.

Comment: My approach is usually to have the list defined not as the pointer to the first node. This makes this kind of code simpler. Simply wrap your list like this (if NodeType is the type of a node in the list: ``typedef struct { NodeType *head; } NodeList;`` The benefit is that you get rid of double pointers, an empty list is not NULL, the NodeList instance can be created on the stack, ...

Comment: The next step to simpler code is to have a sentinel instance in your list type: ``typedef struct { NodeType sentinel; NodeType *head; NodeType *tail; } NodeList; void InitNodeList( NodeList *nodeList ) { nodeList->head = &nodeList->sentinel; nodeList->Tail = &nodeList->sentinel; }`` With that, you save a lot of special cases regarding the wiring of the list for head / tail. And especially this is what went wrong in your code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sorry, what? Must be written back? BitTickler, yeah, that was my idea, have a dummy head....but don't know if it will work, since from what my teachers told me the error is from the free() itself and the compiler

Comment: Can you find out which of the `free`s causes the error, e.g. by printing something before the `free` or by running the code through Valgrind? Is your head node a dummy node?

Comment: @M Oehm as I said in post, my head node is not a dummy head...i think that the problem is from that....

Comment: using a [sentry node](http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1) (dummy head) makes all operations on a linked list special-case free

Comment: It also eliminates the possibility of creating a circular list...

Comment: The issue when deleting the first node is determining if it is in fact a last node. With a circular list, the question is whether the node is self-referencing See: [**C singly-linked circular linked-list example**](http://pastebin.com/BirWtkvb) With a populated first node in a HEAD/TAIL singularly-linked list, you have no way of determining if the node is the only remaining node or simply the last node in the list because both cases will have `node->next=NULL`. However in a double-linked list. You can check `if (node->prev=NULL && node->next == NULL)` then you are last node.

Comment: To turn a double linked list into a circular list, all it takes is 2 more functions: ListCircularNext() and ListCircularPrev() which is trivial to implement. If there is no Next, e.g. in the regular list, you return Head. Same respectively for Prev...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code, but it is apparent that there is only one spot where we can run into a double free.

```
for(i=0;i<nSquareW;i++){
  free(curr->percorridos[i]);
}

free(curr->percorridos);
free(curr);
```

Either you have a case where `curr->percorridos` is the same as `curr`, or maybe `curr->percorridos[i]` is the same as `curr->percorridos`?

You could find this out by adding a print statement before each call to free.  Then find out which is being called twice.

```
for(i=0;i<nSquareW;i++){
  printf("Freeing curr->perrcorridos[i] at %p\n", curr->percorridos[i]);
  free(curr->percorridos[i]);
}

printf("Freeing curr->perrcorridos at %p\n", curr->percorridos);
free(curr->percorridos);

printf("Freeing curr at %p\n", curr);
free(curr);
```

Comment: Your code is wrong....your last print should be curr and not curr->percorridos. Here are the prints:

Comment: So, it seems you have a special case where `curr->perrcorridos` is pointing to the same object as `curr`.  You could place the following line before `free(curr->percorridos)` - `if (curr->percorridos != curr)`

Comment: curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e069a0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06a20
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06aa0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06b20
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06ba0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06c20
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06ca0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06d20
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06da0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06e20
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06ea0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06f20
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e06fa0
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e07020
curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8e070a0
 curr->perrcorridos at 0x8e06960
curr at 0x8e06930

Comment: Freeing curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8056220
Freeing curr->perrcorridos[i] at 0x8056240
*** Error in `./iClean': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08056240 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Actually, there is another case where you things could go wrong.  If `nSquareW` is not equal to size of `curr->percorridos`, you could end up calling free on memory that you did not allocate with `new`.

Comment: At this point, I feel like I need to see more of your code.  What is percorridos?  How is it declared?  What is nSquareW?  How is it declared?

Answer (score 0):

Since double linked list programming questions show up so often on Stack Overflow, my answer will showcase how to do a double linked list in a pretty safe way. It uses a top level list type definition and sentinel entries. There is still some room to mess up, but the code is pretty easy to test and debug as different aspects are treated locally by individual functions.

The delete() function in the original question has the problem that it is in charge of 2 different things: 1. handle the double linked list removal stuff 2. Do some application specific filtering.

My code also shows, that application code running on such a list can be separated from list management code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct NodeType_tag { int32_t value; NodeType_tag *Next; NodeType_tag *Prev; } NodeType;
typedef struct { NodeType sentinel; NodeType *head; NodeType *tail; } NodeList;

void NodeListInit(NodeList * nodeList)
{
    nodeList->sentinel.Next = &nodeList->sentinel;
    nodeList->sentinel.Prev = &nodeList->sentinel;
    nodeList->head = &nodeList->sentinel; 
    nodeList->tail = &nodeList->sentinel;
}
int NodeListIsEmpty(NodeList * nodeList)
{
    return nodeList->head == &nodeList->sentinel;
}
void NodeListAddFront(NodeList* nodeList, uintptr_t value)
{
    NodeType *newNode = (NodeType*)malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
    if (NULL != newNode)
    {
        newNode->value = value;

        newNode->Prev = nodeList->head->Prev;
        newNode->Next = nodeList->head;
        nodeList->head->Prev = newNode;
        nodeList->head = newNode;
        if (nodeList->tail == &nodeList->sentinel)
            nodeList->tail = newNode;
    }
}
void NodeListAddBack(NodeList* nodeList, int32_t value)
{
    NodeType *newNode = (NodeType*)malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
    if (newNode != NULL)
    {
        newNode->value = value;
        newNode->Prev = nodeList->tail;
        newNode->Next = nodeList->tail->Next;
        nodeList->tail->Next = newNode;
        nodeList->tail = newNode;
        if (nodeList->head == &nodeList->sentinel)
            nodeList->head = newNode;
    }
}

NodeType *NodeListHead(NodeList*nodeList)
{
    if (&nodeList->sentinel != nodeList->head)
        return nodeList->head;
    return NULL;
}

NodeType *NodeListTail(NodeList* nodeList)
{
    if (&nodeList->sentinel != nodeList->tail)
        return nodeList->tail;
    return NULL;
}

NodeType *NodeListNext(NodeList * nodeList, NodeType * current)
{
    if (NULL != current)
    {
        if (current->Next != &nodeList->sentinel)
            return current->Next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

NodeType *NodeListPrev(NodeList *nodeList, NodeType *current)
{
    if (NULL != current)
    {
        if (current->Prev != &nodeList->sentinel)
            return current->Prev;
    }
    return NULL;
}

NodeType* NodeListRemoveForward(NodeList* nodeList, NodeType *target)
{
    NodeType* next = NULL;
    if (target != NULL)
    {
        target->Prev->Next = target->Next;
        target->Next->Prev = target->Prev;
        if (target == nodeList->head)
            nodeList->head = target->Next;
        if (target == nodeList->tail)
            nodeList->tail = target->Prev;
        if (&nodeList->sentinel != target->Next)
            next = target->Next;
        free(target);
    }
    return next;
}
// return 1 if value passes filter. 
// return 0 if value is not passing filter.
typedef int(*FilterFunction_t)(int32_t value);

size_t NodeListFilter(NodeList *nodeList, FilterFunction_t filter)
{
    NodeType * current = NodeListHead(nodeList);
    size_t removeCount = 0;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (filter(current->value))
        {
            // passed filter -> keep it.
            current = NodeListNext(nodeList, current);
        }
        else
        {
            // did not pass filter - kill it!
            current = NodeListRemoveForward(nodeList, current);
            removeCount++;
        }
    }
    return removeCount;
}

void NodeListClear(NodeList *nodeList)
{
    NodeType *current = NodeListHead(nodeList);
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current = NodeListRemoveForward(nodeList, current);
    }
}

void DumpNodeList(NodeList* nodeList)
{
    NodeType * current = NodeListHead(nodeList);
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; current != NULL; i++, current = NodeListNext(nodeList,current))
    {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, current->value);
    }
}

int FilterAllOddValues(int32_t value)
{
    if (0 == value % 2)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
void TestNodeList()
{
    NodeList myNodeList;
    NodeListInit(&myNodeList);
    for (int32_t value = 0; value < 10; value++)
    {
        NodeListAddBack(&myNodeList, value);
    }
    DumpNodeList(&myNodeList);
    size_t removeCount = NodeListFilter(&myNodeList, FilterAllOddValues);
    printf("%d nodes removed by filter.\n", removeCount);
    DumpNodeList(&myNodeList);
    NodeListClear(&myNodeList);
}
```

One obvious aspect is, that the number of head/tail special handling if-branches is greatly reduced compared to a non-sentinel implementation.

Another obvious aspect is that I ran it with a c++ compiler and thusly added a cast to the malloc() statements. Please resist the urge to write comments like "Don't cast malloc()", all you hardcore c-programmers ;)

I did a brief smoke test with the test code given below. There still might be errors in functions not covered by the test code.